# Go Channel not responding on load test

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I am running some loadtesting on a go program that use some channels.
Sending message to channel using below code, available [here](https://github.com/tinode/chat/blob/master/server/hub.go#L156)
.

```golang
select {
        case globals.hub.join <- msg:
        default:
            // Reply with a 500 to the user.
            s.queueOut(ErrUnknownReply(msg, msg.Timestamp))
            s.inflightReqs.Done()
            logs.Err.Println("s.subscribe: hub.join queue full, topic ", msg.RcptTo, s.sid)
        }
```

Channel implementation is as below, available [here](https://github.com/tinode/chat/blob/master/server/hub.go#L156).

```golang
select {
        case join := <-h.join:
            logs.Info.Println("hub.go : hub case join")
            ...
            ...

}
```

In normal scenario, the code is working fine, but when loadtested/load is increased to the server,  the channel does not receive mesages sent to it. The channel reaches to a not responsding state. Is there a possible explanation for this?

Any help is appreciated.

Full code of this available [here](https://github.com/tinode/chat/tree/master/server) .

Comment: This information is not sufficient enough to provide a suggestion/solution to the problem. Provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example of the problem to get more attention

Comment: Please provide some piece of code example that matches your problem instead of those abstractions and links, you can't expect that someone will interpret your entire code and logic, right? "loadtested/load" is also very vague, what are the tests? the expectation, the result?

Comment: A channel does not just become unresponsive, you are just not blocked where you think you are. Look at a stack trace to see the status of all goroutines.

Comment: Hi, I use debugger and notice one thing that when i send message to the channel one variable `qcount` on channel object increase but channel not send that to another side in the code ( `case join := <-h.join:` ).